# How can I use colours to separate texture node treatment?

Tags: node-editor

[image: Red & Green: Perfect channel separators]

I'd like to do three things:

1. Make the Red area glossy
2. Make the Green area roughly diffuse
3. Make the Green area appear higher than/on top of the red area (bump height).

Basically I'm looking for a procedural/node technique I can use to treat areas separated by color (or alpha). In the pictured set-up I'm using red and green (as I thought splitting colors to RGB could be a solution), but I'd like the solution to be used with any colors required.

Any clues would be gratefully appreciated :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With two different known colours you can use the **Separate RGB** node:

[image]

The R output of the node already give us a map of the red areas (full white=1)

[image]

You can use the mask both in a Bump Node and in a Mix Shader node.

---

If you would like to implement a similar process with every possible colour you can set up a Node tree capable of recognize where a given color is.

[image]

Basically you have to mask where the the color that correspond to the shader to mix is on the map by masking individually each component. Starting from the **HUE** values we check with math nodes where the subtraction gives almost = 0.

[image]

Than we can copy this node also for the **Saturation** and **Value**...ehm...values! By multiplying their output we are running an Logical AND operation, so at the and we'll have only the places where all three parameters have the same values.

[image]

---

By making a whole group of these operations you'll be able to match each colour to a shader simply by giving the color to pick:

[image]

[image]

Here's an example of usage with files made by an external application such as the [SciFi Helmet](http://quixel.se/usermanual/quixelsuite/doku.php?id=ddo_samples) by Michael Pavlovic. You can pick the colour from the Colour Id mask directly from the render preview.

[image]

Comment: ...It's going to take me weeks to get my head around that Blend file, but WOW! The power! Thanks Carlo!

Comment: I've written a more in depth explanation at: http://carlobergonziniplayground.tumblr.com/post/128405180147/use-color-id-masks-in-blender-cycles (still working on it)

Comment: Hi can we make this work with soft edges ?

Comment: the concept is amazing but for hard sodt edges, it dont work at all https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/136035/edit

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple set up to do what you asked for:

[image: Nodes]

The noise texture is converted to greyscale (a value between 0.0 and 1.0). Then we test to see if the greyscale value is greater than 0.5. (If it's < 0.5 then we get a value of 0.0. If it's greater than 0.5 we get a value of 1.0).

That value of 0.0 or 1.0 can then be used as the factor in a mix shader, and also directly for the surface displacement. (You could add a multiply node in there if necessary).

(I believe the RGB to BW node happens implicitly - as in your set up above, so you could skip it.)