# How make a specific color have a different shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders

So this is my output and material node setup:

[image]

As you can see I want the marked portions to have a glossy shader.

There is another question similar to mine which has been answered here :

[Using an RGB map to assign various shaders in a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90064/using-an-rgb-map-to-assign-various-shaders-in-a-material)

But, I don't know how to integrate that solution into my shader as I'm using a Color Ramp.

Comment: create a black and white image to be used as a mask to control the mix of the diffuse and glossy. Read this related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27475/how-do-you-apply-a-gloss-and-spec-map-on-one-cycles-material/27480#27480

Comment: It's the same exact problem. The solution starts right after the color input (in your case the ColorRamp node, there is the Image Texture) and it's not related to the nature of the input. Here's another related question where it's used a ColorRamp as in your case: [How can I use colours to separate texture node treatment?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38038/how-can-i-use-colours-to-separate-texture-node-treatment/38041#38041)