# Selecting Color-range with the shader editor?

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders

can you do the same action as the color range selection in photoshop inside of blender ? is there anyway you can do this action below ?

[image]

[image]

if its not is it possible trough the compositor? what node is it ?

### ---

---

there is a method out there:
[How can I use colours to separate texture node treatment?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38038/how-can-i-use-colours-to-separate-texture-node-treatment/38041#38041)

it really work well for hard edges, but for soft edges its a mess

[image]

Comment: Look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38038/how-can-i-use-colours-to-separate-texture-node-treatment/38041#38041

Comment: I kno this, it don’t work for soft edges ? Right ?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a technique you can use to select multiple colors, and get soft edge selections.

I borrowed the idea of using a **Vector Math Node** set to `Length` to measure the similarity of colors from [Robin Betts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/222394/2952). It also relates to [this question about replacing colors](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234588/).

This is not an exact replica of the formula that's coded into Photoshop, but it achieves the same thing. In Ps the "**fuzziness**" has a range of values from `0` to `200`, with `100` being the default. While putting together this node setup I got to wondering what "fuzziness" is actually a measurement of, and found out that [it is brightness values](https://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/selections/color-range/). In my node setup the fuzziness is represented in a range of `0.0` to `1.0`.

So instead of using Photoshop's eyedropper in additive mode, we place a custom "**Select Color**" group node for each color we want to add to the color range, and combine them with **MixRGB** nodes set to `Add` and **Fac** set to `1.0`. We can chain as many as desired.

<sub>**Note:** It is also possible to *subtract* from the selection by setting a **MixRGB** node's blend mode to `Subtract` (instead of `Add`). More about the `Subtract` blend mode [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265144/).</sub>

[image: Select Color Range - Blender material node setup]

This is what's happening inside of each "**Select Color**" Group Node:

[image: Inside the "Select Color" Group Node]

The final **Math Node** set to `Subtract` is just inverting the selection so that the selected area is white instead of black.

When dealing with a *selection* mask or *alpha* transparency, we want a range of `0.0` to `1.0`, so enable `Clamp` on the final **Math Node** to ensure the values stay within that range.

The final selection (basically a mask) can be used for anything, but in this example I have it factoring a a **MixRGB** node so that all the selected colors get replaced with a pale green.

Original image ([credit](https://pixabay.com/photos/crayon-colors-colorful-education-215873/)):

[image]

Selection (mask):

[image]

Example result:

[image]

That's basically all there is to it, and this can be customized in various ways to select ranges of colors for whatever purpose.

---

**2023/02/16 update:**

Blend file added.

[image]

<sup>(Created with Blender ver. 3.4)</sup>

**General notes on color mixing and selection**

(Things that will be obvious to many people, but maybe not everyone.)

- In my example I am using the **Mix** node to simply *replace* the selected area with a solid color fill, however by changing the blend type in the drop-down from `Mix` to another type you can get different effects. For example, `Hue` will colorize the selected area with a new hue.
- To change a selection with soft edges to one with hard edges, one simple way is to run it through a **Math** node set to `Greater Than` and adjust the Threshold.
- To make selection edges hard*er* (but not necessarily completely hard), you can route the selection through an **RGB Curves** node and shape the curve into an S-curve or a steep linear curve. The steeper the curve, the harder the edges become.

Comment: would you mind posting the Blender file, I am having a hard time replicate your direction.

Comment: @ajthechan Done! :-)