# How to get Vector Length in the compositor?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, mathematics, vector

I have a **Material** node setup that processes color and I want to recreate that node tree for the **Compositor**.

Unfortunately the setup relies on a `Vector Math : Length` node to accomplish what it does.

Looking at the [Blender Manual's entry for the Vector Math node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/converter/vector_math.html), we can see that Length is performing the following function:

[image]

Can this be replicated using `Math` nodes in the Compositor?

Comment: Well, even without looking into the _Blender Manual_, this formula is simply the formula for the _Euclidean distance_, the length of a line segment between two points in _Euclidean space_. And since everything is written out there and you have a _Math_ node in the _Compositor_, I'm a bit confused what is the problem to recreate it... anyway, Robin provided an answer for you. If his multiplying the X, Y and Z values with themselves does not look close enough to the original formula for you, you could instead of _Multiply_ set the nodes to _Power_ and choose 2  as _Exponent_.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann (_Power_  avoided, for efficiency, but no great shakes)

Comment: @RobinBetts I would have done it that way, too... but since not everybody might have great math skills I just mentioned it if something like $A_x \cdot A_x$ looks wrong to him compared to $A_x^2$.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Bingo! I don't understand mathematical notation, so I wouldn't be certain whether to do `(A * A)*x` or `A*(x*2)` and since I don't want to patch something together based on assumptions, I just ask. *But the math makes perfect sense to me when I see it in the form of Blender nodes!* I realize there would probably be value in studying mathematical notation at some point, but that can be said of many things. Will I ever get around to it? Remains to be seen... :-) And by posting Q&A about it, hopefully others of limited math skills will also find this info helpful.

Comment: @Mentalist Yes, I think maths can be challenging sometimes. Especially since working with Blender in many tasks not necessarily requires math skills from the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup. Just transcribe the expression, and group it up:

[image]

Comment: Worth a check though, that whatever color-processing you're doing, is not already provided by the compositor,  internally ..

Comment: Thank you! The purpose is to approximate the operation which in Photoshop terminology would be called **Select → Color Range...** Here is a [Material Nodes solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/281605/2952), which is based on previous contributions of yours (see links in that answer).  ;-)

Comment: @Mentalist Hehe ... I thought it might be :) That's provided by the [Distance Key](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/matte/distance_key.html) node. Variations are available, whereby you can set separate thresholds for H,S,and V, for example.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks for mentioning that. Having inter-compatibility between node types (Materials/Compositor) is satisfying in its own right though - so even if there is overlap with an existing node's functionality, a custom `Vector Math: Length` node is still welcome, as far as I'm concerned. ;-) But I will definitely play around with `Distance Key` as well. Cheers.

Comment: [Here's a .blend](https://blend-exchange.com/b/KSqW9JKD/) of what I've been tinkering with, in case you're curious to see how your answer helped. Matching Compositor/Material node setups for isolating image hue. A bit geeky... maybe not useful to everyone... but I'm pretty happy about it.